# What's the difference between multe and ofte?

Tags: word-choice

When should an Esperanto speaker say *ofte*, and when *multe*?
A definition of *ofte* is 'often', a definition of *multe* is 'a lot'. When does an Esperanto speaker use which?

An example, what would be used with the following?

```
Mi ofte/multe uzas vian vortaron.
/mi 'of.te/'mul.te 'u.zas 'vi.an vor'ta.ron/
Mi   oft  -e   / mult -e    uz -as   vi -an    vortaro   -n   .
1SG  often-ADV / a_lot-ADV  use-PRES 2SG-GEN   dictionary-ACC .
I use your dictionary often/a lot.
```

Comment: What did your dictionaries say? "often" and "a lot" are *glosses*, not definitions.

Comment: Also, what dictionary are you using? "a lot" seems quite colloquial to me, and I would expect a translation glossary to prefer "many" or "multiple" for _multe_, based on the meaning and usage of the cognates in European languages.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I used wiktionary.org for these, but I agree many or multiple would fit better. As I am asking the question, I don't know if choosing another one would make the question unanswerable. '(Very) much' is also used elsewhere,

Comment: Downvoters care to explain what could be improved?

Comment: In any case, when you have multiple glosses for a word, you want to choose the gloss that best fits your context. I would expect that an Esperantist would use _ofte_ where an English-speaker would use "often", and _multe_ where an English-speaker would use "many", "multiple", or other quantity-suggesting words.

Comment: Please answer the question if you have an answer, the comment section is for discussion and the like. Also, the question asks from English to Esperanto—not from Esperanto to English.

Comment: I downvoted for lacking research as I indicated in my comment: glosses are not definitions and are not substitutes for them.

Comment: The definitions I gave, as in one of my comments above, are the definitions, according to the dictionary. Furthermore, glosses *are* substitutes for definitions, as glosses replace full definitions but leave out information and other details to be shorter. Finally, I disagree 'lack of research on gloss vs. definition' is enough reason to downvote, as only ill-researched posts are a reason to downvote, and glosses not being definitions is but a small detail. Esperanto has a dedicated Epo.SE site, but there is no policy restricting Esperanto posts on Conlang.SE as of yet.

Comment: Hello. It sucks being bullied at another SE. Hope you get more friendly responses here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I support Jeff's comment that the difference between *ofte* and *multe* is the same as *often* and *a lot* as in English.

Basically, if your use of their dictionary is 20 times in the last hour, you *uzas multe*. If it is every day in the last 20 days, you *uzas ofte*.

And if you use it 10 hours a day for months, you *uzas multofte* or *uzas multe ofte*.

Comment: And if you use it 10 hours a day for months, you _uzas multofte_ or _uzas multe ofte_.

Comment: @Vidamuzo Thank you! I added your answer as well.